# Is there any connector in mule which connects an API to bank system APIs?

Tags: mule

I want to access bank API by my API but I am unable to find any connector in mule that can connect the APIs

Answer (score 0):

@arpit, your question is very generic.
To connect to bank API, you should find out:
 how exactly is bank exposing data(REST/JSON)?
 what is underlying technology(Java/C/OFS)? 
 what is the protocol used(HTTP/HTTPS/TCP)?

Answer (score 0):

If a connector for your restful Bank API does not exist on the Anypoint Exchange you can create a connector for it.

https://docs.mulesoft.com/anypoint-connector-devkit/v/3.7/creating-a-connector-for-a-restful-api-using-restcall-annotations